# Google app scripts doesn't get GET requests from arduino

Tags: http, google-apps-script, https, arduino, get

I am using Arduino IoT to send a GET http request to a google app scripts(which is linked to a google sheet but not the issue here). I used this code numourus times with no issues, but now I don't see any exestuations going on the script meaning no request is arriving.
This is the http request code on arduino side:

```
    int httpRequest() {
  static WiFiClient client;
  static const char WEBSITE[] = "script.google.com";

  String url = "/macros/s/" + GAS_ID + "/exec?deviceID=" + (String) deviceID
       + "&smA="      + (String) sm[0]
       + "&smB="      + (String) sm[1]
       + "&smC="      + (String) sm[2]
       + "&smD="      + (String) sm[3]
       + "&smE="      + (String) sm[4]
       + "&smF="      + (String) sm[5]
       + "&smG="      + (String) sm[6]
       + "&smH="      + (String) sm[7]
       + "&smI="      + (String) sm[8]
       + "&smJ="      + (String) sm[9]
       + "&smK="      + (String) sm[10]
       + "&smL="      + (String) sm[11]
       + "&smM="      + (String) sm[12]
       + "&smN="      + (String) sm[13]
       + "&smO="      + (String) sm[14]
       + "&smP="      + (String) sm[15];

  if (client.connect(WEBSITE, 443)) {
      Serial.println("connecting...");
      client.print(String("GET ") + url);
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1"); 
      client.print("Host: ");
      client.println(WEBSITE);
      client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
    Serial.println("Sent data");
    
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
    return 1;
  } else {
    Serial.println("failed to connect to http");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I double checked that the GAS id is correct, I suspect it is some kind of a permission issue but I allowed all users even anonymous to access and edit the script(did it in the first web app publish)
Did something change in GAS protocol or I have a mistake here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033383/how-to-send-a-valid-http-request-to-a-google-apps-script-web-app

Comment: @Cooper I didn't understand the bottom line. I should use a certain library that will do the transitions from http to https? what is that library?